# Android tv box disable startup or replace video

Tags: android, startup

I bought a new android tv box called: km8 pro and it runs Android marshmallow...

In the startup there's a video with km8 logo and musics.

I've tried to change the bootanimation.zip file but it still plays the same video.

Is there anyway to disable or replace it?

Comment: anyone???......

Answer (score 2):

The video you see is a video at `/etc/bootvideo`

You need root access. Remount /system, and rename /etc/bootvideo to /etc/bootvideo.bak. The boot animation file will now be used.

Comment: Should be comment!

Comment: @Div why? It's a short answer but it does answer the question.